# How to add a "pipe" into a get parameter during guzzle query building

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm using an api that has a "range" parameter that can apply to several different parameter items. The range i'm focusing on is "price". I'm using guzzle in laravel and according to the api documentation, the query for this particular parameter should be written like this "&range_facet=price|500|2500|250"...this is broken down into the minimum, maximum, and interval values of the price range parameter. That's not necessarily important to this question. When i try and run this query as is, i get nothing returned. When I remove that particular parameter, i get values but obviously they're not filtered the way i want them to be. When i run this in Insomnia, the pipes are replaced by "%7C", which is obviously (obviously?) not interpreted by the api as it's not how it's waiting for the GET request to be made. How can I insert the pipes into the query so that it calls the correct way?

I've tried to create an additional nested array with the price value being broken up into key value pairs but that didn't work either.

```
'range_facets' => ['price'['start'=>'500', end=>'2500', 'interval'=>'250']],
```

```
$client = new Client();
      $result = $client->request('GET', "http://api.example.com", [
    'headers' => [
        'Host' => 'example-host',
        'Content-Type'     => 'application/json'
    ],
    'query' => [
      'api_key' => 'my_api_key',
      'range_facets' => 'price|500|2500|250',
      'year' => $year,
      'latitude' => '30.170222',
      'longitude' => '92.01320199',
      'radius' => 500,
      'start' => 0,
      'rows' => 50
    ]
]);
```

I'd like to filter my prices but I need the pipe to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how it should be. `%7C` should be decoded on the server side to `|` automatically ([about query string encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding)).

I bet the issue is in different place.

Comment: You are correct. I had to reach out to the API developer. It took them several days to get back to me, that's why i posted my issue here. But once they did get back, they had to address an error in the API. Thanks for the answer.